# Unity PhotoCapture return 'No capture devices are available.' ERROR on Hololens2

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I am tring to take a picture or get a stream video in Hololens2 and I am used Unity: 2020.3.2f1 Platform: UWP.

I am trid to test this sample:
https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Windows.WebCam.PhotoCapture.html

But when I test this sample on my Hololens2 device I get two error like:
'The stream number provided was invalid.'
'No capture devices are available.'

This is my Unity project setting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4rH3.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu90b.png)

I also enalbe Package.appxmanifest microphone an WeCam,uninstall the app from hololens2 and build again and deploy but I still get the two error.

Is there anyway to fix this error?

Please forgive me for being terrible in my English.

---

This is my current code.
I think I only invoke one Media API.

```
using Microsoft.MixedReality.OpenXR;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Windows.WebCam;


public class Capture : MonoBehaviour
{
/// <summary>
/// Allows this class to behave like a singleton
/// </summary>
public static Capture instance;

/// <summary>
/// Keeps track of tapCounts to name the captured images 
/// </summary>
private int tapsCount;

/// <summary>
/// PhotoCapture object used to capture images on HoloLens 
/// </summary>
private PhotoCapture photoCaptureObject = null;

/// <summary>
/// HoloLens class to capture user gestures
/// </summary>
private GestureRecognizer recognizer;

//Test

private HoloLensCameraStream.Resolution _resolution;
private VideoCapture _videoCapture;

void Awake() {
    instance = this;
}

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start() {
    // Initialises user gestures capture 
    //recognizer = new GestureRecognizer();
    //recognizer.SetRecognizableGestures(GestureSettings.Tap);
    //recognizer.Tapped += TapHandler;
    //recognizer.StartCapturingGestures();
}

private void ExecuteImageCaptureAndAnalysis() {
    Resolution cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending
        ((res) => res.width * res.height).First();
    Texture2D targetTexture = new Texture2D(cameraResolution.width, cameraResolution.height);

    PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(false, delegate (PhotoCapture captureObject)
    {
        photoCaptureObject = captureObject;

        CameraParameters c = new CameraParameters();
        c.hologramOpacity = 0.0f;
        c.cameraResolutionWidth = targetTexture.width;
        c.cameraResolutionHeight = targetTexture.height;
        c.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.BGRA32;

        captureObject.StartPhotoModeAsync(c, delegate (PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
        {
            string filename = string.Format(@"CapturedImage{0}.jpg", tapsCount);
            string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, filename);

            // Set the image path on the FaceAnalysis class
            //FaceAnalysis.Instance.imagePath = filePath;
            photoCaptureObject.TakePhotoAsync
            (filePath, PhotoCaptureFileOutputFormat.JPG, OnCapturedPhotoToDisk);
        });
    });
    Debug.Log("Success!");
}

/// <summary>
/// Called right after the photo capture process has concluded
/// </summary>
void OnCapturedPhotoToDisk(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result) {
    photoCaptureObject.StopPhotoModeAsync(OnStoppedPhotoMode);
}

/// <summary>
/// Register the full execution of the Photo Capture. If successful, it will begin the Image Analysis process.
/// </summary>
void OnStoppedPhotoMode(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result) {
    photoCaptureObject.Dispose();
    photoCaptureObject = null;
}

public void CaptureImage() {
    ExecuteImageCaptureAndAnalysis();
}

}
```

Comment: "The stream number provided was invalid." is a WinRT error and usually cause by the UWP API MediaCapture. However, the PhotoCapture API you mentioned is an Unity API, did you invoke two different Media API for capturing? It seems like there a race condition occurs cause both PhotoCapture and MediaCapture make operations on the camera.

Comment: I think I only invoke one Media API.I had edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create a new Unity project and try the following code, it works for me in the HoloLens2:

```
public void StartCap()
{
    PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(false, OnPhotoCaptureCreated);

}
private PhotoCapture photoCaptureObject = null;

void OnPhotoCaptureCreated(PhotoCapture captureObject)
{
    photoCaptureObject = captureObject;

    Resolution cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();

    CameraParameters c = new CameraParameters();
    c.hologramOpacity = 0.0f;
    c.cameraResolutionWidth = cameraResolution.width;
    c.cameraResolutionHeight = cameraResolution.height;
    c.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.BGRA32;

    captureObject.StartPhotoModeAsync(c, OnPhotoModeStarted);
}
private void OnPhotoModeStarted(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
{
    if (result.success)
    {
        string filename = string.Format(@"CapturedImage{0}_n.jpg", Time.time);
        string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, filename);

        photoCaptureObject.TakePhotoAsync(filePath, PhotoCaptureFileOutputFormat.JPG, OnCapturedPhotoToDisk);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Unable to start photo mode!");
    }
}
void OnStoppedPhotoMode(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
{
    photoCaptureObject.Dispose();
    photoCaptureObject = null;
}

void OnCapturedPhotoToDisk(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
{
    if (result.success)
    {
        Debug.Log("Saved Photo to disk!");
        photoCaptureObject.StopPhotoModeAsync(OnStoppedPhotoMode);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Failed to save Photo to disk");
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I miss some step to initialze my project so I sill get that two error. 
First I creat a new 3D project and then I follow "Initializing your project and deploying your first application" to initialze my project.
In the end,I created a gameobject and add the script to the gameobject.
At the same time I call the 'StartCap' function to capture photo.

Have I missed any steps so far?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,I think the question is down.

I trid the code form 'Hernando - MSFT' but it still return the two error,but when I open the Hololens Windows Device Portal and open the project folder I can see the picture!!!

I also test my origianl code,and it is work too.

I didn't know why it always return the two error when I capture a picture,but I think it didn't attack the capture function.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpHCE.png)